# How to structure my projects around windows 255 character limit H E L P

Tags: java, filesystems, structure, project

I have a project where my file structure looks a bit like this:

```
StartMenuFrame:
    StartMenuFrame.java
    StartMenuPanels:
        StartMenuMainPanel:
        StartMenuMainPanel.java
        StartMenuMainPanelComponents:
            MyFirstComponent.java
```

etc.

how do i keep my project src code structured and easy to navigate through while staying within the 255 character limit.

I MUST STAY IN THE 255 LIMIT. I have tried to allow it in the registry but it does not seem to work with git and github as only code in the 255 character limit gets committed to the repository.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean when following this naming scheme you get file names with more than 255 characters?

Comment: @bkis I get an entire path which is longer than 255 characters and windows does not support this.

Comment: Get rid of StartMenuMainPanelComponents and move everything under it up one level.  Subpackages are mainly for restricting access (like the `friend` keyword of C++), not for fine-grained organization.  It’s perfectly acceptable to have fifty classes in a single package.  I would seriously consider moving everything in StartMenuMainPanel up a level as well.